# invalid subscript 'texcoord'

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am pretty new to Unity 3D and just trying to implement this tutorial: http://bernieroehl.com/360stereoinunity/

When creating the adapted Shader that he is describing I made a new unlit shader and input his two lines of code the `Cull front` and the `v.texcoord.x = 1 - v.texcoord.x;`

Now I get an exception

> Shader error in 'Unlit/insideOut': invalid subscript 'texcoord' at
>   line 43 (on d3d11)

Any idea what could be wrong?

The whole shader:

```
Shader "Unlit/insideOut"
{
Properties
{
    _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    Cull front
    LOD 100

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        // make fog work
        #pragma multi_compile_fog

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            v.texcoord.x = 1 - v.texcoord.x;
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
            UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            // sample the texture
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            // apply fog
            UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`texcoord` is not a member of `appdata`. Either use `v.uv` :

```
v.uv.x = 1 - v.uv.x;
```

or rename the `uv` member to `texcoord`

Answer (score 0):

Names can be changed in struct appdata, so can also change in struct appdata
float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
for
float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
(but couldn't change TEXCOORD0 cos that's used internally by unity)